# How to import variables to gtk css file from another css file

Tags: css, terminal, gtk

I would like to import color variables from another css file to my gtk.css file, they are in the same directory.

So my **colors.css** is:

```css
:root {
    --bg-color: #101e21;
    --colo1: #a0bcca;
    --colo2: #a0bc2a;
}
```

I tried to import this in my **gtk.css** with:

```css
@import url("colors.css");

.termite {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

Is it possible? If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Note that if I use an hexadecimal value for background-color my terminal displays the color normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file may be importing fine, but GTK CSS doesn't support CSS variables. (CSS variables are relatively new.) GTK CSS has its own syntax for defining color variables, which predates the CSS variable syntax: [`@define-color`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html#id-1.5.2.3.8).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to ptomato's answer, I found the right way of importing color variables in gtk css.

**colors.css** is now:

```
@define-color bg-color #101e21;
```

**gtk.css** is now:

```
@import url("colors.css");
.termite {
    background-color: @bg-color;
}
```